# Having problems integrating with SimpleUPC API on iOS

Tags: ios, afnetworking

So I'm relatively new to this and I'm running into a problem that has me pretty stumped.  SimpleUPC provides a pretty simple API but they have the following format for a JSON request:

```
{
"auth":"Your API Key",
"method":"MethodName",
"params": {
    "paramName":"paramValue",
    "paramName2":"paramValue2",
},
"returnFormat":"optional"
}
```

I also download their Ruby sample which I have verified does work from the command line.

```
# Sample API calls using JSON...
host = "api.simpleupc.com"
path = "/v1.php"

# An example query for FetchProductByUPC method
request = {
    "auth" => 'Your-API-Key',
    "method" => 'FetchProductByUPC',
    "params" => {"upc" => '041383096013'}
}

json = request.to_json()


response = Net::HTTP.start(host) { |http|
    http.post(path, json, initheader = {'Content-Type' =>'text/json'})
}

output = response.body

puts output
```

Ok so far so good.  But here's my code that is trying to do the same thing but I am getting errors complaining about missing parameters.

```
NSDictionary *requestDict = @{@"auth": kSimpleAPIKey, @"method": @"FetchProductByUPC", @"params":@{@"upc": code}};

[[SimpleUPCClient sharedClient] getPath:@""
                             parameters:requestDict
                                success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

                                    NSLog(@"Response: %@", responseObject);

                                }
                                failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

                                    [TMReportingHandler handleError:error fatal:NO];

                                }];
```

I know this has got to be something simple I'm doing wrong but I can't figure it out.  Anyone?

Comment: Can you post the error text?

Answer (score 0):

Wow, I knew it was something simple.  Turns out it was expecting a POST instead of a GET...I switched it and it worked immediately.